# Hive select query with Group by minute

Tags: date, select, group-by, hive, minute

I have data of the form as below:

```
hive> desc test;
no string
txdate string
hive>

hive> select * from test;

1  2014-06-01 10:12:12.100

1  2014-06-01 10:12:14.100

1  2014-06-01 10:12:16.100

1  2014-06-01 10:13:12.100

1  2014-06-01 10:14:12.100
```

I need to group the data using txdate column and truncated to the last minute. Output should be as below

```
3  2014-06-01 10:12:00

1  2014-06-01 10:13:00

1  2014-06-01 10:14:00
```

Can anyone help me with the Hive select query to solve this?

Comment: Would you like to tell us what you have tried? You can use `GROUP BY` in `HIVE`.

Comment: Look at from_unixtime() and unix_timestamp()

Answer (score 2):

We can use substr() function to make this possible.

Query is:

```
select substr(txdate,1,16), sum(no) from test group by substr(txdate,1,16);
```

The result of this query will be

```
2014-06-01 10:12 3
2014-06-01 10:13 1
2014-06-01 10:14 1
```